# Unresolved reference to CLR UDT type

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, clr, user-defined-types

I've got a problem. In VS 2013 I've created my own UDT type:

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedType(Format.UserDefined, IsByteOrdered = true, ValidationMethodName = "ValidateInput", MaxByteSize = 170)]
public struct Pesel : INullable, IBinarySerialize
```

Then I've added to the project a new table query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    [Name] TEXT NOT NULL, 
    [Pesel] [dbo].[Pesel] NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([Pesel]) 
)
```

When I try to build my project I get this error:

```
SQL71501: Column: [dbo].[Person].[Pesel] has an unresolved reference to Built-in Type [dbo].[Pesel]
```

What am I doing wrong? When I delete create table query, build the project and create new type manually, everything is ok. I can create my table.

Comment: won't solve your problem, but while UDT's seem like a good idea, I no longer use them.

Comment: Are you sure the table script is in the same project, as opposed to another project in the same solution? I was able to get this to work. On a related note, please do _not_ use the datatype `TEXT` as it has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005. Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead.

Comment: I don't know what I've done, but now after building my project, everything is ok. So problem solved.